# Python: Tkinter, areas around labels and button will not change colour

Tags: python, tkinter, colors

```
from tkinter import *



class MyWindow(Frame):
  def __init__(self,parent):
    Frame.__init__(self,parent)

    root.configure(bg = "cornsilk")



    def Exit():


        print("your name is", Name.get())
        print (f"You are {Age.get()} years old")
        print("Your favourite pastime is", Pastime.get())

        root.destroy()


    def GetData():


        def Restart():
            top.destroy()

        top = Toplevel()
        top.title("correct?")
        top.geometry("200x200")
        lbl = Label(top, text = "Is this all correct?", fg = "red")
        lbl.place(x=30, y = 0)

        Correct_Name = Label(top, text = f"your name is {Name.get()}.", fg = "blue" )
        Correct_Name.place(x=30, y=33)

        Correct_Age = Label(top, text = f"You are {Age.get()} years old.", fg ="blue")
        Correct_Age.place(x=30, y=66)

        Correct_Pastime = Label(top, text = f"You like {Pastime.get()}.", fg = "blue" )
        Correct_Pastime.place(x=30, y=99)

        Submit2 = Button(top, text = "yes", fg ="blue", command = Exit)
        Submit2.place(x = 30, y = 132)
        Submit3 = Button(top, text = "no", fg ="blue", command = Restart)
        Submit3.place(x = 60, y = 132)


    label1 = Label(self, text = "What is your full name?", fg="red")
    label1.grid()
    Name = Entry(self, fg = "blue")
    Name.grid()


    label2 = Label(self, text = "how old are you?", fg ="red")
    label2.grid()
    Age = Entry(self, fg = "blue")
    Age.grid()

    label3 = Label(self, text = "What is your favourite pastime?",fg = "red")
    label3.grid()
    Pastime = Entry(self, fg = "blue")
    Pastime.grid()



    Submit_All = Button(self, text = "submit", command = GetData)
    Submit_All.grid()

    myWidgets = [label1, label2,label3, Submit_All] # List of widgets to change colour
    for wid in myWidgets:
        wid.configure(bg = "cornsilk")


root = Tk()

MyWindow(root).grid()

root.title("Survey")
root.mainloop()
```

This code creates a mini survey in a tkinter gui, i would like to know why certain areas of background around labels, entry boxes and my button are not changing colour, help is appreciated!

(Get Data is not currently meant to have background colour)

i would also appreciate it if anyone could tell me how to add an imae to the top of the first box, Thanks!

edit: The same method of changing the colours works perfectly in my top box now that I added it. Main Frame still broken.

Comment: what colors do you expect things to be?

Answer (score 0):

As near as I can tell, you need to add `self` to `myWidgets`, or add a separate statement in `__init__`.  If that does not answer your question, please clarify it.